# Laravel cache path?! Never seen before

Tags: laravel

> InvalidArgumentException in Compiler.php line 36:
>   Please provide a valid cache path.

Having the above error while trying to deploy an existing app to a new server. Sure I have covered every basis, however maybe I have missed something!?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: which laravel version ?

Comment: Do you have a .env?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that those folders exists :

`./storage/framework/cache`

`./bootstrap/cache`

Answer (score 2):

Please Create below folders under **Storage/framework**

1. **sessions**
2. **views**
3. **cache**

than run following command

```
sudo composer install
```

Please check if issue is still there.

Comment: Thanks @shwet,  views folder was missing. It worked after I created it an assigned permissions.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. Folders did exists, is latest version of Laravel and .env was fine.

Ran a clear-compiled and a composer dump-autoload and is now fine.